# Sort Data in Desc Order in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter and working on maintenance project. I want to sort the data in descending order according to end date. Here is query:

```
       $this->db->select('*');    
       $this->db->from('deals');   
       $this->db->where('id IN ('.$new_data.')');
       $this->db->where('status !=', 'expired');
       $this->db->where('status !=', 'draft');
       $this->db->order_by('end_date','DESC');
```

This query does not give my preferred result.

end_date is of field_type "varchar" and stored in format "m/d/y"

Comment: change datatype to date

Comment: Firstly: kc1994 is probably right, varchar is not the right type to save a Date. Secondly: I personally prefer to work with unix_timestamps to save dates (you store it as an Integer). Since datetime in mysql always seem to trouble everyone. [see here](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php) for a mysql example for unix_timestamps

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->order_by(DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%m/%d/%Y'),'DESC');
```

OR

```
$this->db->order_by(STR_TO_DATE(end_date,'%m/%d/%Y'),'DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$q = 
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('deals')
    ->where("(id IN '{$new_data}' AND status != 'expired' OR status != 'draft')")
    ->order_by(STR_TO_DATE('end_date','%m/%d/%Y'),'DESC')
    ->get();

print_r($q->result_array());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("*,STR_TO_DATE(end_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS day",FALSE);
   $this->db->from('deals');   
   $this->db->where('id IN ('.$new_data.')');
   $this->db->where('status !=', 'expired');
   $this->db->where('status !=', 'draft');
   $this->db->order_by('day','DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Data Contains in $data['deal_list'] array. You can Sort as:

```
$tempArr = $data['deal_list'];

// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($tempArr as $key => $row) {
    $dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y",$row['end_date']);
    $timestamp = $dtime->getTimestamp();
    $volume[$key]  = $timestamp;
}

array_multisort($volume, SORT_ASC, $tempArr);
$data['deal_list'] = $tempArr;
```